# Can I run ubuntu from a CD?

Tags: installation

I have installed as primary OS windows XP sp3. Would like to have too ubuntu 12.04 or 11.10 but will be more benefit for me to run from a CD. It's mean i like to install ubuntu not in the hard disk but in a CD. Can I do this? and how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can, but you won't be able to save any data. If you want a portable installation that you can save data on, you can [use a USB drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick).

To install ubuntu on a CD, follow the directions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) to make an installation CD or USB drive. When you boot from this CD/drive, you will be asked whether you want to "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu". Choose "Try Ubuntu" to run Ubuntu from your CD/USB drive.

Comment: Or you can use the Live CD and just save any data you want kept on a USB stick.  The plus side is your settings and applications can never be harmed because they are fixed.  The down side is that you can never change your settings or install new applications, and you will have no remembered history (which could also be a plus side if you are very privacy-conscious).